# How to get this checkbox toogle to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am creating a toggle checkbox with my own CSS and Jquery but got stuck, actually i want my inner-box to slide from left to right and right to left onclick event as well as changing the text from Yes to no and No to Yes.

My CSS file is as:

```
.outer-box{
background:green;
padding:5px;
width:50px;
height:20px;
}

.inner-box{
background:blue;
padding: 2px;
width:17px;
height:17px;
display:inline;
}
```

JS File is as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.outer-box').click(function(){
    var value = $('.outer-box').attr('id');
    alert(value);
    if(value === 'right-box'){
       // alert(value+" -- ");
        //$('.outer-box').text('N');
         $('.inner-box').css('float','left');
         $('.outer-box').text('N');
         $('.outer-box').removeAttr('id');
         $('.outer-box').attr('id','left-box');   
    }else if(value === 'left-box'){
         $('.inner-box').css('float','right');
         $('.outer-box').text('Yes');
         $('.outer-box').removeAttr('id');
         $('.outer-box').attr('id','right-box'); 
    }                
  });    
 });
```

And My Html File is as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <title>Feed back Form</title>
 <head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="self.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="self.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<div class="outer-box" id="right-box" > Yes
        <div class="inner-box" style="float:right;"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
 </body> 


</html>
```

I want my checkbox button to be like this : http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/zqKtp
can anybody help me out

Comment: I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kF4QL/) recreating your code so people can experiment; feel free to edit your question to include this if you think it will help.

Comment: Why don't you use the pen you posted? Or do you want better browser support? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: For those who prefer to work in vanilla JS, [Here is a vanilla JS version](http://jsfiddle.net/KLe6B/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$('.outer-box').text('N');` you are overwriting your `<div class="inner-box" style="float:right;"></div>` so it doesnt appear anymore. What you could do is wrap the text in a span and change the text of that element, so you no longer overwrite your sliding box.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kF4QL/1/

Comment: if i want to animate the inner div from left to right. How should i go about it. I have tried animate function from Jquery but not getting it to work. and after animating will i will be able to achieve the text "Yes" & "NO" after wrapping the text in <span>.                                                              Instead of using the float can i move the element left and "No" text should appear on the right. and similarly i should be able to animate the it on right and "Yes" text should appear

Comment: I would do the animations in CSS. Heres an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kF4QL/14/ You should really look into using the checkbox hack method mentioned here: http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Answer (score 0):

Please find my observations on your code:-

1. left-box id is not defined
2. var value = $('.outer-box').attr('id'); you will always get the value as right-box only.
   If you are looking for click event on a particular div, you need to use event target to identify it and then toggle the div